Kretschmann Scalar for the FLRW Metric
I am trying to understand the Wikipedia definition of the Kretschmann scalar for a cosmological solution.
The metric is given by the standard FLRW metric
\begin{equation*}
ds^2 = -dt^2 +a^2(t)\left(\frac{dr^2}{1-kr^2} + d\Omega^2\right).
\end{equation*}
Assuming $[r] = [L]$ we have that $a(t)$ is dimensionless and $[k] =[L^{-2}]$.
For such a metric they provide
\begin{equation*}
K = 12\left[\frac{a''(t)^2}{a(t)^2}+\frac{ (k+a'(t)^2)^2}{a^4(t)}\right].
\end{equation*}
For dimensional reasons, the operation $A'$ must be $A' =dA/dr$, but I don't understand why they keep the spatial derivatives of $a(t)$, since it should be zero in the FLRW metric. Hence, I expect that
$$K =\frac{12k^2}{a^4(t)}.$$
Is this interpretation of the derivation symbol correct?

Why downvoting without leaving a comment?

$c=1$ so $[t] = [L]$

Oh you are absolutely right, i was confused because usually $dA/dt = \dot{A}$ for the time derivative. If you want to make this a (short) answer i will accept it :)

The answer they provide is correct. Your expectation is wrong. What is the reason for you to expect this?

It is a time derivative. The choice of coordinates is such that $c = 1$ (as one can see from the metric). Hence, your dimensional argument still works with the time derivative. Furthermore, of course, time is the only parameter of the scale factor, so the derivative couldn't be with respect to anything else.
If you want to compute it explicitly just to check it out, the Kretschmann scalar is not defined by this formula: that is just a particular case (the FLRW metric). The definition of the Kretschmann scalar is
$$K = R^{abcd}R_{abcd},$$
i.e., the full contraction of the Riemann tensor with itself. As you can imagine, the Riemann tensor will involve time derivatives of the scale factor, and in the end you learn that they are arranged in this particular way.

Yes, i know that the definition is different. As stated in the comments, since i didnt remember that in natural units T=L and usually a primed variable means spatial derivative, i was confused by that notation. Thank you for your answer :)
